# How to get the content of an article via a webservice on Joomla 2.5

Tags: web-services, joomla2.5

I need to get the content of an Article which is on my Joomla website. In order to do this, I was planning to write a simple PHP webservice to get the content (HTML) of my article. But I just don't know how to do this.

I'm new in Joomla, web developping and web services. I just want to get the content of my article in order to display it in my ruby on rails site.  Can anyone explain how I can do this?

Comment: As far as I know Joomla2.5 doesn't give a simple solution to do this, so you would have to write a significant amount of custom code to do this. Far more than I expect anyone would write for you on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is at least a small contribution that should help to get you going: the attached code can be called with "?id={ID of article you want to retrieve}" and it displays the entire object on screen. 
Next steps: pick out the pieces you're interested in and return these...

```
    <?php

    define('_JEXEC', 1);
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    $username="*** insert username ***";
    $password = "*** password here ***";

    if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
        define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
        require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
    }

    require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php';

    // Mark afterLoad in the profiler.
    JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterLoad') : null;

    // Instantiate the application.
    $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

    // Initialise the application.
    $app->initialise();
    $app ->login(
         array('username'=>$username,    
               'password'=>$password), 
         array('remember' => true)); 
    $dbo = JFactory::getDBO();

    $id=$_GET["id"];
    $art = JTable::getInstance('Content');
    $art->load($id);

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($art);
    echo"</pre>";
```

?>

Comment: Yeah thanks for your quick answer, but i need to be authenticate on Joomla in order to get the article. How can i do this in my webservice in php ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, im begin to understand how joomla work for manipulating the site outside a web browser. However, when i login, i always on the page login. And i want to be on the article page. Can i pass the login page in order to access to my article ?

Comment: Is it possible at all for you to post the complete .php-file you've written?

Comment: I actually use yours, i just add some xpath code (in order to get the content of my article) which is comment actually :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your problem.  (a) it should not be neccessary to login in order to read the content (even "Special"-articles can be retrieved with this approach w/o being logged in) and (b) when I execute this code I am in no way taken to the login-page. Have you placed the .php-file in the root of your Joomla-installation (where index.pgp resides, too)?

Comment: Yes i did, the problem is, when i use the webservice to retrieve an article, (IF MY CACHE WAS CLEANED) i automaticly redirect to the login page, even so i use your way to login. And i put the php-file on the root of the Joomla site. But if i was already logged (via the site and no my webservice), it works.

Comment: Strange - works for me. Did you replace username/password in the code?

Comment: So, if you are taken to the login when trying to run that code, is it possible that .hatccess is redirecting you? Can you (for a moment) try to rename .htaccess and cal the .pgp again, does that make a difference?