# call a function in class of joomla from external file

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I need call a function in one class of joomla from another php file inside the joomla folder.

for example i have a extension in joomla that have a function for import data from xml file in admin section. 
this function  is similar this code

```
    class importXML extends importBase {

       public function doImport()
       {  ........
       }
    }
```

i need call this function in cronjob, can i doing this?
any idea?

ps: the joomla version is 2.5

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: for example Iproperty extension have a function for import data from xml or csv but i need call this function automaticaly in cronjob

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible - but also depends on what parts of the Joomla-Environment this extension expects to find.
Have a look @ [How to get the content of an article via a webservice on Joomla 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883332/how-to-get-the-content-of-an-article-via-a-webservice-on-joomla-2-5/17895349) - this might help to get going, but it could be that you get errors which hopefully help to prepare a better context for runnung that code...

Comment: Oh, and certainly such a script can be launched through a cronjob, no problem. Let's work that out once we got past the 'details' of your question...